# How to detect browser support for pageShow and pageHide?

Tags: javascript, dom, browser-detection, browser-support

How can we do JavaScript object detection for [pageShow and pageHide](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Using_Firefox_1.5_caching) handlers?

```
if( /* pagehide is supported */ ){
   window.addEventListener('pagehide', exitFunction, false);
}
else{
    window.addEventListener('unload', exitFunction, false);
}
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

```
if ('onpagehide' in window) {
   window.addEventListener('pagehide', exitFunction, false);
} else {
   window.addEventListener('unload', exitFunction, false);
}
```

Comment: I just checked. Answer works, but has a flaw. If someone defines onpagehide before this check happens window.onpagehide would be true. I am not sure if there is anyway to avoid that. :(

Comment: @epascarello That's possible with just about anything. You can redefine `getElementById` with `document.getElementById = "nyan cat";`

Comment: most browsers will not let you set getElementById. That one is protected. :)

Comment: This answer worked for me in chrome but not firefox although both do support pageshow (I tried with pageshow), firefox always fails the conditional check.

Comment: @Shaz The recommended way to check if an event is supported is to use `if ('onpagehide' in window) {`. (See http://perfectionkills.com/detecting-event-support-without-browser-sniffing/ There are a very few exceptions for broken browsers. Expanding on @nilfalse's comment.)

Comment: The link in the comment above is 404. Here's the updated one: [Detecting event support without browser sniffing](http://perfectionkills.com/detecting-event-support-without-browser-sniffing).