# jQuery .unload() issue in Safari

Tags: jquery

Im dynamically populating image into a container div, using the $.post() function.
Whenever I have a different filtering for the images, I abort the current request, however, I have troubles when navigating to another page on my site. Ive realised, that I should abort the current request there as well, however, it struggles under Safari while not under Chrome.

Initialising the request:

```
var request = $.post( ... );
```

When running another one:

```
request.abort();
request = $.post( ... );
```

When navigating away, to another page:

```
$(window).unload(function() { request.abort(); });
```

Could there be any reason why it **does not work or at least, not always** under Safari?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please take a look at this question:
[Why is jQuery unload not working in chrome and safari?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9973816/why-is-jquery-unload-not-working-in-chrome-and-safari?rq=1)

The `unload` function is not part of any standard, so you actually can't be sure if the unload function gets called in a browser.

Try:

```
$(window).on('beforeunload ',function() {
    request.abort();
});
```

instead.

**UPDATE**

Another solution can be the following. Your users probably navigate to another page with links. So, using jquery, update the `onclick` behaviour of links: first abort request, then navigate to the new page.

Comment: that does not solve the problem created by closing a tab in the browser or simply closing the window. :(

Comment: UPDATE: your original solution works, but now it only works under Safari and not under Chrome.. sorry.. bad troubleshooting

Comment: so now the task at hand is to solve the same thing under Chrome

Comment: What you tried first (in your question) is working in Chrome? If yes, just detect the browser and use the solution for that browser.

Comment: I mean, in your question you said: `$(window).unload(function() { request.abort(); });` works in Chrome. Isn't it?

Comment: Actually.. Ive just realised that i messed something up with the troubleshooting and thats why i switched from `beforeunload` to `.unload()`.... but then I did not realise that Chrome blocks the alert windows and I was not checking the console.....
SO! Back to the original `beforeunload` ... that works everywhere.
Again: My fault. Sorry.

Comment: I catch onClick event of the anchor tag. Use e.preventDefault() with a global variable to avoid loop , do my stuff and then $(this).trigger('click') to use the default behaviour of the anchor but the trigger click does not work. any point on this?

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately Safari doesn't support unload event. Instead you should use `pagehide`.

Here you one example:

```
<html>
    <head>
    <script>

    function pageShown(evt)
    {
        if (evt.persisted)
            alert("pageshow event handler called.  The page was just restored from the Page Cache.");
        else
            alert("pageshow event handler called for the initial load.  This is the same as the load event.");
    }

    function pageHidden(evt)
    {
        if (evt.persisted)
            alert("pagehide event handler called.  The page was suspended and placed into the Page Cache.");
        else
            alert("pagehide event handler called for page destruction.  This is the same as the unload event.");
    }

    window.addEventListener("pageshow", pageShown, false);
    window.addEventListener("pagehide", pageHidden, false);

    </script>
    <body>
    <a href="http://www.webkit.org/">Click for WebKit</a>
    </body>
    </html>
```

I suggest you to read this: https://www.webkit.org/blog/516/webkit-page-cache-ii-the-unload-event/

And if it's possibile choose another solution, don't use unload!

Comment: well, i made this out of it, since i only want to handle situations occurring on tab closing, window closing or simply navigating away in the browser..
`window.addEventListener("pagehide", function(ev){if(!ev.persisted){alert('abort');request.abort();} }, false);`
and it did not work.. even the alert did not show up.. and it did crash the browser couple of times.

Comment: It doesn't work in pwa. Do you have any information about it?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function(e) {
    return 'Safari.';
};
```