# Cannot prevent refreshing page in window.onunload()

Tags: javascript, jquery, mobile-safari

I'm trying to show a prompt message in case user trying to refresh the page.
I used window.onbeforeunload and it's working fine on other browsers BUT not Mobile Safari.

I'm trying to use window.onunload for Mobile Safari, I can show the prompt message, but cannot prevent refreshing page.

Below is the code

```
<script>
    var iOS = ( navigator.userAgent.match(/(iPad|iPhone|iPod)/g) ? true : false );
    if(iOS){

        window.onunload = function() {
            var test = confirm("Are you sure you want to leave this page");

            if(!test){
                return false;
            } 

        }
    }
```

I also tried the pagehide event, can show the prompt but still cannot prevent refreshing page
Below is the code

```
<script>

  window.addEventListener("pagehide", function(){
    var test = confirm("Are u sure you want to leave this page aaaaaaaaaaaaa");         
    if(!test){          
        return false;
    } 
  },false);

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Read this answer

[Why is jQuery unload not working in chrome and safari?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9973816/why-is-jquery-unload-not-working-in-chrome-and-safari?rq=1)

You cannot have any dialogs/confiems in beforeunload.

```
jQuery(window).on('beforeunload', function() {
  return 'Are you sure you want to leave this page';
});
```

Comment: I tested on iPad, using Mobile Safari and I can see the prompt message. But the page is still reloadding

Comment: i think it's the default prompt not your custom one.

Comment: It's mine, not the default one.

Answer (score 0):

As of some information from this site:

https://www.webkit.org/blog/516/webkit-page-cache-ii-the-unload-event/

onbeforeunload and onunload not working in safari. So I suggest you try using the pagehide event in the safari browser. Pls try and let me know

http://www.w3schools.com/jquerymobile/event_pagehide.asp

Comment: I just tried the pagehide event, I can see the prompt but cannot prevent refreshing page. I added code sample for using pagehide() in the question, please refer.

Answer (score -1):

### Try this

```
$(window).on('beforeunload', function() {
  return 'Your own message goes here...';
});
```

Comment: As mentioned in the question, I used beforeunload(), but it doesn't work on Mobile Safari. So I need a special handler for Mobile Safari