# Event to be triggered when leaving website or closes the browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I´m trying for a while execute a JavaScript function when a user leaves web site by typing a address in the browser and hits return or the user closes the browser clicking in the <kbd>x</kbd> button.

I tried the unload event but I cannot get the alert.

This is what I am doing:

```
$(window).unload(function () {
    alert("Are you sure?");
});
```

also

```
$(body).unload(function () {
    alert("Are you sure?");
});
```

I am running out of ideas!

Comment: [this is what you're looking for](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6065085/467164)

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery - beforeunload](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6063522/jquery-beforeunload)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can listen to `beforeunload` event that fires before the unload event, when the page is unloaded.

```
$(window).on('beforeunload', function(){
    // ...
})
```

Comment: beforeunload expects you to return a string, I believe, which is probably worth pointing out.

Answer (score 2):

Some browsers (like Chrome) block alerts in unload event handlers, to prevent exactly these kind of annoying messages. Try a console.log or put a breakpoint in to find out if the handler is triggered when you don't have an alert there.

SO question on a similar line:

[window.onunload is not working properly in Chrome browser. Can any one help me?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7794301/window-onunload-is-not-working-properly-in-chrome-browser-can-any-one-help-me)

You can only pass the alert by [returning a string in a beforeunload handler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6063522/jquery-beforeunload/6065085#6065085) (HT @undefined), but I would avoid even that, because popups are generally bad, and most people will do minimum processing to work out the make-this-thing-go-away option before they actually think about the contents of the box.

Answer (score 1):

The function you defined in window.onbeforeunload if it returns a string it will pop up a confirm navigation prompt with that message.

**Alerts may be ignored!**

```
window.onbeforeunload = function() {
    return "All unsaved data will be lost. Are you sure?";
};
```

**Some browsers handle the onbeforeunload differently.  Recent Firefox for example will ignore your return string and just display a standard message.**

Answer (score 0):

```
$(window).bind('beforeunload', function(){
    alert("Are your sure?")
});
```