# Javascript not working in Chrome

Tags: javascript

```
window.onbeforeunload = function() { logout();};
function Logout()
  {
     window.location.href = "logout URL";
   return false;
  }
```

My requirement is: when user clicks close button, user should be logged out. It is working fine in IE. But not working in Chrome.

Can any one please suggest.

Comment: You have a lowercase L for `Logout()` in your code - is that a typo, or in your code?

Comment: possible duplicate of [window.onunload is not working properly in Chrome browser. Can any one help me?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7794301/window-onunload-is-not-working-properly-in-chrome-browser-can-any-one-help-me)

Answer (score 4):

Your function name is `Logout()` not `logout()`. [Case Sensitivity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Case_sensitivity)

Comment: Sorry it is lower case only logout()

Comment: No. Iam writing this script in JSP page

Comment: @user2632735 you should update your post to correct this typo to not mislead people to answer on something that isn't the actual problem.

Comment: sorry for that. Any idea on resolving the issue.

Comment: @user2632735 Seriously, it is unconvenient way of logging user out. You can store the time when user logged in then start a loop in JS to send AJAX request to PHP and see which user is inactive for more than 20 seconds. If found anyone, set it as logged out. I cannot write full code for you but its a suggestion.

Comment: @ Akbar. Thanks for that. But we have mechanism for inactive time. We have a req where user should be logged of if user closes the browser. User session should be terminated for that reason iam calling logout URL.

Comment: @user2632735 I have dealt with login systems, I applied the same idea as explained above. It worked nicely.

Answer (score 1):

Try,

```
window.onbeforeunload = logout;

function logout() {
  window.location.href = "logout url";
  return false;
}
```

**UPDATE:**

First is to check whether logout function is ever getting called by putting alerts in 
logout function or if you are using newer versions of chrome then use `console.log('called')`.

You can try this alternative to check:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function() {
    logout();
    return null;
}

function logout() {
     window.location.href = "logout url";
}
```

Comment: Why not just `window.onbeforeunload = logout;`

Comment: Code optimizations are always great. Thanks for clarifying. Agreed!

Comment: what is console.log('called') which one i need to replace by called?

Comment: first try with alerts to check if `logout` is ever got called.

Comment: do you want me to show alert when we access close button? We are getting alert message when we try to close window. But we are not logging of the user. Is there any issue with window.location.href in chrome?

Comment: Well probably in modern browsers. You can try, `window.location.assign("logout url");`

Comment: Please try to put actual url in the href and also try the setTimeout method that should work on all browsers: `setTimeout(function(){window.location.href = "logout.html;"},500);`

Answer (score 0):

```
logout() !== Logout()
```

Try the below one

```
window.onbeforeunload = logout;
function logout()
  {
   window.location.href = "logout URL";
   return false;
  }
```

Comment: Sorry it is lower case only logout()

Comment: @user2632735 I guessed. try this `window.onbeforeunload = logout;`

Comment: @user2632735 `window.onbeforeunload = logout;
function logout()
  {
  return window.location.href = "http://jsfiddle.net/"; 
  
  }`  try returning the logout url

Comment: tried returning logout url. No luck. I think there is some problem with window.location.href

Comment: Maybe check your logout url.

Comment: It is working fine in IE. how come it don't work in Chrome? Any idea?

Comment: I'm also amazed, why don't you check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7794301/window-onunload-is-not-working-properly-in-chrome-browser-can-any-one-help-me

Comment: i din't understood what exactly need to be done by seeing the blog. Can you pls let me know what to do?

Comment: @user2632735 Try like this`$(window).on('beforeunload', function() {
    window.location.href = "logout URL";
   return false;
});` .on() is not thing but an event handler attachment.