# onunload inside <body> does not work on Google Chrome

Tags: javascript

Browser compatibility please give me answer......

```
window.onbeforeunload = beforeunload;
window.onunload = function() {
    clearTimeout(showMsgTimer);
    retrieveURL("/janus/Logout.do?param=removeUserManagementLocksForController");
```

But its not working inside the chrome browser only. Its working on IE & Firefox. In the Chrome browser even an alert inside the `window.onunload = function()` will not get executed. How can I execute this one in Chrome. Is there any other way we can do it? (can't use the `window.onbeforeunload = function()` also)

Comment: It is JavaScript which is not Java! These two languages are totally different.

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7794301/window-onunload-is-not-working-properly-in-chrome-browser-can-any-one-help-me You should find the answer there.

Answer (score 1):

```
      window.onunload = function(){
      alert("Are you sure?");
      }
```

If you want to use jQuery, this will work in all browsers.

```
      $(window).unload(function () {
      alert("Are you sure?");
      });
```

That's because Chrome blocks alerts in the onunload event.

**Window.onbeforeunload**

Note that it use 'return' to prompt message before closing the page.

```
      <script type="text/javascript">
      window.onbeforeunload = Call;
      function Call() {
        //alert("Unload Called");
        return "You are going to close this window?";
      }
      </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

For onunload in all browser except opera by changing the asynchronous in to synchronous call request.

```
xmlhttp.open("POST","LogoutAction",false);
```

and its worked well for all browsers except Opera.

Comment: can you paste your code here so that i can explain you with your piece of code.

Comment: window.onbeforeunload = beforeunload;

window.onunload = function () {
 clearTimeout(showMsgTimer);
 retrieveURL("/janus/Logout.do?param=removeUserManagementLocksForController");