# Close window after confirmation box

Tags: javascript, html

Need the following **code** to work and make a confirmation alert appear after **clicking** on a button.

It's kinda of a **"exit website button".**

> *Confirmation appears:*
>   **Clicks "OK" >** current window close;
>   **Clicks "Cancel" >** confirmation alert close;

**HTML**

```
<a href="#"><i class="fa fa-power-off" onclick="closeWebsite()"></i></a></div>
```

**Javascript**

```
<script>
  function closeWebsite(){
    window.close();
  }
</script>
```

Where's my mistake? I'm currently learning **Javascript**.

Comment: "Where's my mistake?" — What makes you think you've made a mistake? Why do you expect that code to display a confirmation alert? What does that code actually do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You can only use JavaScript to close a window/tab that was spawned via JavaScript.**

Just create file with name `index.html` and open the another tab, just first click on Open and Then on Close you will get the answer

```
<a href="index.html" target="blank">Open</a>
<a href="#" onclick="closethis();return false;">close</a>

<script>
function closethis()
{
    if(confirm("Close Window?")){
        close();
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: My pleasure, can you please mark this as a right answer.

Answer (score 0):

Does this help you?

```js
function closeWebsite(){
 var resultConfirm = confirm("Confirm window close?");
 if (resultConfirm == true) {
  console.log("closing window...");
  window.close();
 }
}
```

```html
<a href="#"><i class="fa fa-power-off" onclick="closeWebsite()">Close window</i></a></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot close a window with javascript that you did not open. It will not work in chrome or firefox.

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/19768082/2623781 for more information.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are really looking for is the **window.beforeunload** event, which get triggered when you leave the website.

It does not matter how you leave it (by closing the tab/browser or surfing to another website).

Here you find an example of how it works: [window.onunload is not working properly in Chrome browser. Can any one help me?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7794301/window-onunload-is-not-working-properly-in-chrome-browser-can-any-one-help-me/9325742#9325742)